# qmake ui header file location

Tags: c++, qmake

I modified my c++ Qt4 project to that all the sources are in an src directory. All the temporary file are stored in a build directory and the target file in a bin directory. Here a snapshot of my .pro file

```
SOURCES += src/*.cpp
HEADERS += src/*.h
FORMS   += gui/myguy.ui

INCLUDEPATH += src/         # Source directory to be included
DESTDIR     =  bin          # Target file directory
OBJECTS_DIR =  build        # Intermediate object files directory
MOC_DIR     =  build        # Intermediate moc files directory
```

my problem is the following. When I build the application qt automatically transforms ui_mygui.h. This is by default stored on the root of the project. How can I specify the location where I want this file to be put?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UI_DIR` variable. This is where those files will be generated.